# Multiplus input upload

Tags: php, upload

Gostaria de adicionar mais input files dinamicamente.
Quero poder adicionar mais imagens e colocar uma legenda para cada imagem. sem um limite para uploads.

Comment: pouca informação, tenta postar código para podermos ajudar

Comment: Tenho apenas um formulário simples, porem gostaria de adicionar vários uploads dinamicamente, por exemplo, tem um upload padrão, porem se eu quiser adicionar mais 2 uploads, eu adiciono no mesmo form. entendeu?